# Is there a way to print out a row of text only if it's being used?

Tags: c#, console-application

[link  to full code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MUmuXKKZ4WTZrOesscPI_hii3aL9c6cL)

I'm creating a small cafe application. After I've prompted the user to enter their details, enter the item code and qty they want to order, I want to get a print output in the final bill only of the things they've ordered.

tl;dr: I want the bill to print out details for an ordered (e.g) cheesecake only if they've ordered cheesecake, I dont want the other menu items to appear on the bill.

I've printed out the header for the application manually. I then ran it into an if condition to see if a certain function was occurring and if so to print the details respectively (e.g: If you ordered 3 cheesecake, it will print its details on the bill.)

```
Console.WriteLine("|    Item Code   |" + "|    Item Name    |" + "|    Item Cost    |" + "|     Qty Ordered     |");

double totBillCost = 0;
            if (makeOrder.orderCode == 1)
            {
                totBillCost = totBillCost + (cheesecake.itemCost * makeOrder.orderQty);
                Console.WriteLine("      "+ cheesecake.itemCode + "      " + cheesecake.itemName + "      " + cheesecake.itemCost + "      " + makeOrder.orderQty);
        }
```

I hope this makes sense. I basically want it to output the details for an order of cheesecake when its ordered.

I have a total of 4 items in the menu if that matters.

Comment: We need full code.

Comment: Right now it's impossible to answer your question. We need to know what exactly you're doing, how do you select the items? And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: How about creating a generic model for all the orders then a method let's say `PrintOrder(order)` which can have a static format for the bill where the values are generated based on the generic order model passed as parameter.

Comment: @vikscool I was thinking the same, It's be cool to have a more dynamic menu though >w<

Comment: Code in the *actual question itself*. Don't expect people to go offsite and download a random zip file they cannot verify.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ISellable> boughtItems = new List<ISellable>
        {
            new BottleOfWater(),
            new Sugar(),
            new Chocolate(),
            new Sugar(),
            new BottleOfWater(),
            new BottleOfWater(),
            new BottleOfWater(),
            new BottleOfWater(),
            new BottleOfWater()
        };

        Console.WriteLine("| Name | Price | Amount |");

        List<IGrouping<Type, ISellable>> groupedBoughtItems = boughtItems.GroupBy(x => x.GetType()).ToList();

        foreach(IGrouping<Type, ISellable> group in groupedBoughtItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("| {0} | {1} | {2} |", group.First().Name, group.First().Price, group.Count()));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("| Total | {0} |", boughtItems.Sum(x => x.Price)));
    }
}

public interface ISellable
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    double Price { get; set; }
}

public class BottleOfWater : ISellable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public BottleOfWater()
    {
        Name = "Bottle Of Water";
        Price = 2.55;
    }
}

public class Sugar : ISellable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public Sugar()
    {
        Name = "Sugar";
        Price = 1.3;
    }
}

public class Chocolate : ISellable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public Chocolate()
    {
        Name = "Chocolate";
        Price = 50;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want to probably aggregate (`GroupBy`) so you can get a Qty Ordered.

Comment: Yeah I added it, i forgot ahah